# Agrupamento tabela

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Eu tenho essa tabela e gostaria de montar uma lista ou outra tabela

```
     users_ID_User                                           Material  Rating
0            A            "Hey Pogo!...from citation to fulltext"       5
1            B            "Hey Pogo!...from citation to fulltext"       4
2            C            "Hey Pogo!...from citation to fulltext"       5
3            D            "Hey Pogo!...from citation to fulltext"       4
4            D              "Julius Caesar" Speech Analysis StAIR       4
5            A              "Julius Caesar" Speech Analysis StAIR       4
6            B              "Julius Caesar" Speech Analysis StAIR       4
7            E              "Julius Caesar" Speech Analysis StAIR       4
8            E  "Virgin Birth" method promises ethical stem cells       5
9             A  "Virgin Birth" method promises ethical stem cells       3
10             D                   .NET Overview, VB.NET and C#.NET       5
11            C                   .NET Overview, VB.NET and C#.NET       4
12            D  1 Project Management and Software Engineering ...       4
13             A  1 Project Management and Software Engineering ...       4
14             S  1 Project Management and Software Engineering ...       4
15             B  1 Project Management and Software Engineering ...       4
16            A  1 Project Management and Software Engineering ...       4
17           C                       10 Best Foods 10 Worst Foods       1
18             D                       10 Best Foods 10 Worst Foods       2
19           E                       10 Best Foods 10 Worst Foods       4
20           E                           100 preguntas de química       0
21           F                           100 preguntas de química       0
22           G                           100 preguntas de química       0
23           A                           100 preguntas de química       2
24           B                           100 preguntas de química       0
25           C                           100 preguntas de química       4
26           E                           100 preguntas de química       5
27           A                           100 preguntas de química       4
28           F                           1000 Quick Writing Ideas       2
29           A                           1000 Quick Writing Ideas       0
```

estou utilizando pandas, eu tentei:

```
df_3 = pd.read_csv("tabela_final_1.csv",delimiter=",")
del df_3['Unnamed: 0']
df_3 = df_3.drop_duplicates(['users_ID_User','Material'])

df_3 = df_3.pivot('users_ID_User','Material','Rating')
```

não funcionou como eu gostaria, estou tentando montar.

```
Usuario   Hey Pogo !...       Julius Caesar ...  Virgin Birth ... 
A                     5           4
B                     4           4
C                     6           NaN
D                     4           NaN
E                     NaN          5                    5
```

e no final ordenar pela linha que tem mais a rating...

no caso mostrado  ficaria primeiro A, B, E ......

Gostaria de uma logica para montar essa tabela, estou meio confuso!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma estratégia simples é criar uma coluna de contagem de avaliações maiores que 0, ordenar a tabela usando essa nova coluna como critério, e então dispensá-la.

Para isso, o código abaixo resolve

```py
import pandas as pd

# do exemplo do autor:
# df = pd.read_csv("tabela_final_1.csv")
# del df['Unnamed: 0']
# df = df.drop_duplicates(['users_ID_User','Material'])
# df = df.pivot('users_ID_User','Material','Rating')

# Criando a coluna de quantidade de avaliações:
# - `df > 0` resulta em Trues para valores > 0
# - `.sum(axis=1)` soma os Trues de cada linha
df["num_ratings"] = (df > 0).sum(axis=1)

# Reordenando a tabela.
df = df.sort_values("num_ratings", ascending=False)

# Excluindo a coluna auxiliar das contagens.
df = df.drop("num_ratings", axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução que encontrei foi: pegar os valores únicos das colunas 'users_ID_User' e 'Material', gerar um novo dado por meio de um dicionário e inserir esse dado com um append em um outro dataframe. (No meu exemplo usei o seu dataframe até o index 9)

Pegar os valores únicos:

```
lista_valores_unicos_ID = list(set(df['users_ID_User'].values))
>>> print(lista_valores_unicos_ID)
['B', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'D']

lista_valores_unicos_material = list(set(df['Material'].values))
>>> print(lista_valores_unicos_material)
['"Julius Caesar" Speech Analysis StAIR', '"Virgin Birth" method promises ethical stem cells', 'Hey Pogo!...from citation to fulltext']
```

Agora crio um dataframe vazio com o modelo de saida desejado:

```
data_resposta = {'users_ID_User':[], 'Rating':[]}
for elemento in lista_valores_unicos_material:
    data_resposta.update({elemento:[]})

df_resultado = pd.DataFrame(data=data_resposta)
```

Para facilitar, criei um dataframe com os 'Ratings' já calculados, assim posso só pegar esse valores:

```
df_groupby = df.groupby('users_ID_User').agg({'Rating':'sum',})
>>> print(df_groupby)
               Rating
users_ID_User        
A                  12
B                   8
C                   5
D                   8
E                   9

#Pego eles assim
>>> print(df_groupby.loc['A'].values[0])
12
```

Posso pegar a ocorrência de cada frase da coluna 'Material' de um usuário específico assim:

```
df_unico_A = df.loc[df['users_ID_User'] == 'A']['Material'].value_counts().to_frame()
>>> print(df_unico_A)
                                                   Material
"Julius Caesar" Speech Analysis StAIR                     1
"Virgin Birth" method promises ethical stem cells         1
Hey Pogo!...from citation to fulltext                     1

#Iterando por linha
>>> for index, row in df_unico_A.iterrows():
        print(index, ':', row['Material'])

"Julius Caesar" Speech Analysis StAIR : 1
"Virgin Birth" method promises ethical stem cells : 1
Hey Pogo!...from citation to fulltext : 1
```

Agora itero para cada usuário da lista `lista_valores_unicos_ID` pegando os as ocorrências com a lógica acima, colocando em um dicionário, e insiro os dados no `df_resultado` com um append:

```
for id in lista_valores_unicos_ID:

    nova_data = {'users_ID_User':id, 'Rating':df_groupby.loc[id].values[0]}
    for elemento in lista_valores_unicos_material:
        #Cada frase é inicializada com uma contagem 0
        nova_data.update({elemento:0})

    df_unicos = df.loc[df['users_ID_User'] == id]['Material'].value_counts().to_frame()

    for index, row in df_unicos.iterrows():
        nova_data[index] = row['Material']

    #for i in (0,len(df_unicos)):
    #    nova_data[df_unicos.index[i]] = df_unicos.values[i]

    df_resultado = df_resultado.append(nova_data, ignore_index=True)
```

Agora o `df_resultado` é a saída esperada, mas falta ordenar:

```
df_resultado = df_resultado.sort_values('Rating', ascending=False )
```

Agora sua saída deve ser algo como: (Eu cortei as frase manualmente e coloquei '...', mas não alterei os valores obtidos)

```
>>> print(df_resultado )
   "Julius...   "Virgin...   Hey Pogo!...   Rating   users_ID_User  
1         1.0          1.0            1.0     12.0               A  
3         1.0          1.0            0.0      9.0               E  
0         1.0          0.0            1.0      8.0               B  
4         1.0          0.0            1.0      8.0               D  
2         0.0          0.0            1.0      5.0               C
```